# what is this weird viewport shading?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, shaders

Part of this mesh is now shaded in the viewport in solid mode with this look that changes shade when you rotate the view. Like a hologram.

What is it?

Blender... where you hit the wrong key combo and 2 hours later have no idea what obscure hidden feature you've enabled.

[image]

Comment: this might be because your mesh normals are a little out of wack.  Try going to edit mode, press "A" to select everything, and then press "Shift N" to recalculate your normals

Comment: At first sight, it also looks as if some of your faces are set to shade flat (in Edit mode), and some are not.

Comment: @ETHANDAY It's not normals, that didn't fix it. Thanks though.

Comment: @RobinBetts Seems that setting everything to shade-flat doesn't fix it either. 
I think it has something to do with the materials that I'm using in the submesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was this setting under object data parameters. "Normals->auto smooth" Which is somehow different from the other ways of doing it.

[image]